# How to validate configuration based on Data Annotations?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, data-annotations, .net-7.0

How do I validate this configuration based on the Data Annotations I put?

```cs
var dbConfiguration = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AWS:DynamoDB").Get<DynamoDbConfiguration>();

public class DynamoDbConfiguration
{
    [Required]
    public required string AccessKey { get; init; }

    [Required]
    public required string SecretKey { get; init; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)")]
    public required string ServiceUrl { get; init; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"(us(-gov)?|ap|ca|cn|eu|sa)-(central|(north|south)?(east|west)?)-\d+")]
    public required string Region { get; init; }
}
```

Comment: on the client side or the server side? not sure what you are actually asking

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro on server side. ASP.NET Core Web API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddOptions<DynamoDbConfiguration>()
    .Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AWS:DynamoDB"))
    .ValidateDataAnnotations()
    .ValidateOnStart();

var myApp = builder.Build();
myApp.Run();
```

Output:

```
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsValidationException: DataAnnotation validation failed for 'DynamoDbConfiguration' members: 'AccessKey' with the error: 'The AccessKey field is required.'.; DataAnnotation validation failed for 'DynamoDbConfiguration' members: 'SecretKey' with the error: 'The SecretKey field is required.'.; DataAnnotation validation failed for 'DynamoDbConfiguration' members: 'ServiceUrl' with the error: 'The field ServiceUrl must match the regular expression '[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)'.'.; DataAnnotation validation failed for 'DynamoDbConfiguration' members: 'Region' with the error: 'The Region field is required.'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
```

The `ValidateDataAnnotations` extension method is defined in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations` NuGet package. For web apps that use the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK, this package is referenced implicitly from the shared framework.

[more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0#options-validation)

Comment: Thanks, that works but however it would be nice if someone provides a FluentValidation solution, cuz some people wire it up with it.